# React and TypeScript: How to pass Arguments to Event handler of type: MouseEventHandler

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How do I define the event handler: `handleStatus` of type: `MouseEventHandler` so that I can pass an additional argument of type: `Todo` to the function?

```js
interface TodoProps {
  todos: Array<Todos>        
  handleStatus: MouseEventHandler,
  index: number,
  className: string
}
    
export const Todo: FunctionComponent<TodoProps> = ({ todos, handleDeleteTodo, handleStatus, index, className }): ReactElement => {
  const d_todo: Todos = todos[index];
  return(
    <> 
      <div className= { className } key={ todos[index].id.toString() }>
        {todos[index].describtion}
        <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index])  }  />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

I got the Error:

```
ERROR in src/components/Todo.tsx:29:84
TS2345: Argument of type 'Todos' is not assignable to parameter of type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>'.
  Type 'Todos' is missing the following properties from type 'MouseEvent<Element, MouseEvent>': altKey, button, buttons, clientX, and 29 more.
    27 |             <div className= { className } key={ todos[index].id.toString() }>
    28 |                 {todos[index].describtion}
  > 29 |                 <Button lable='' disabled= { false } onClick= { () => handleStatus(todos[index])  }  />
       |                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
    30 |                 
    31 |             </div>
    32 |         </>
```

Comment: Why have you given `handleStatus` the type of `MouseEventHandler`, then proceeded to give it a `Todos` instead of a `MouseEvent`?

Comment: My intention is to change a specific todo, so I need to give a todo as an argument

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not able to understand. Do you need to pass both `MouseEventHandler` and `Todos` to handleStatus?

Comment: yes, I need to pass both.

Comment: Because, in the handleStatus function is a forEach function which compares the passed argument with an array todos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need to pass both event `MouseEvent` and both `Todo` then you need to declare `handleStatus` as a function that accept an event and a `Todo`:

```js
handleStatus: (event: MouseEvent, todo: Todo) => void
```

then in the component:

`onClick={(event) => handleStatus(event, todos[index])}`

Comment: Thank you so much. You made my Day

Comment: @Pad.Schwende you are welcome